# Spring compass hibernate integration

Tags: spring, hibernate, compass-geolocation

Can any one give example for Spring compass hibernate integration for web application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This one](http://sanjsuya.wordpress.com/2012/02/01/compass-spring-hibernate-integration/) is well explained IMHO.